# Magento installation in windows

Tags: mysql, sql, magento

While installing Magento I'm facing this error-
Entering into: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php?route=/database/sql&db=magento

I go to SQL and search for

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data`(`path`, `value`) VALUES (‘dev/static/sign’, 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value`=0
```

and it returns this error:
[image: 1]
MySQL said: Documentation

> #1054 - Unknown column '‘dev' in 'field list'

Answer (score 1):

Replace with this:

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data`(`path`, `value`) VALUES ('dev/static/sign', 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value`=0;
```